# Consecutive timestamps in R

Tags: r

In R, I have a dataframe with two columns: one for a user id, and one for a login date.

Each user id appears several times in the dataframe, each time with a corresponding login date. How could I compute which users were logged in for any consecutive 3 days?

For example, in the below dataframe, we would select users 1 and 3.

- 1........2017-01-01
- 2........2017-01-01
- 3........2017-01-01
- 3........2017-01-02
- 1........2017-01-02
- 1........2017-01-03
- 3........2017-01-03
- 2........2017-01-04
- 3........2017-01-09
- 1........2017-01-12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution. I create a custom function to check if there are three consecutive days in the login column, and then I use it in `summarize` in the `dplyr` pipeline:

```
user <- c(1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1)
login <- c('2017-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-04', '2017-01-09', '2017-01-12')

df <- data_frame(user, login)

three_consecutive_days <- function(x) {
  x <- sort(date(x))
  if(length(x) >= 3) {
    for(i in 1:(length(x) - 2)) {
      if(ymd(x[i]) + ddays(2) == ymd(x[i + 2])) {print('found a true'); return(TRUE) }
    }
  }
  return(FALSE)
}

df %>%
  group_by(user) %>%
  summarise(three_consecutive_days = three_consecutive_days(login)) %>%
  filter(three_consecutive_days == TRUE)

##    user three_consecutive_days
##   <dbl>                  <lgl>
## 1     1                   TRUE
## 2     3                   TRUE
```